# How to configure GraphQL SPQR to use Gson instead of Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, gson, graphql-spqr, graphql-spring-boot

I noticed that GraphQL-SPQR has at least a couple properties that you can configure (e.g. `graphql.spqr.gui.enabled=true`). Is there a configuration for specifying to use Gson instead of Jackson for object serialization/deserialization?

If there is not configuration, is there some other way I can use Gson instead of Jackson for GraphQL-SPQR?

> NOTE: I am already using `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson` in my `application.properties`, to override spring in general to use Gson instead of Jackson, but it doesn't seem to override GraphQL-SPQR's value mapper (defaults to Jackson).

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is register a `ValueMapperFactory` bean, e.g.

```
@Bean
public ValueMapperFactory gson() {
    return new GsonValueMapperFactory();
}
```

To customize the factory, use the builder instead of the constructor:

```
@Bean
public ValueMapperFactory gson(Gson gson) {
    return GsonValueMapperFactory.builder()
            .withPrototype(gson)
            .build();
}
```

You can find most customizable beans listed [here](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter/blob/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter-v0.0.4/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/io/leangen/graphql/spqr/spring/autoconfigure/SpqrAutoConfiguration.java#L68).

I also think respecting `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper` is a great idea. I'll add that in a future release. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter/issues/66) for progress.

Be warned though that Gson mapping is much simpler than Jackson's. It has a lot less features, only takes fields into accounts (not constructor parameters or setters) and will likely not behave exactly the same as Jackson-based mapping. But I guess you're aware of that since you explicitly wish to use it.